She held a little of a feeling of self-contempt

She held a little of a feeling of self-contempt. [my sentence]

Does a little of a feeling of self-contempt sound idiomatic?
My intuition tells me that native English speakers would use a different phrase.

Thank you very much, Mari Lou.. I made a terrible blunder. I've changed it to "self-contempt".

That edit makes a lot more sense now. :) "She felt a little self-contempt" would be my choice.

Thank you. I used "held" to indicate the feeling is not permanent. Would "was feeling" instead of "felt" work?

That would work also.

We don't speak of 'holding a feeling'. You could also say "She had a slight feeling of..."

Thank you, Kate Bunting. Does "She was having a slight feeling of ..." sound odd to you?

Proofreading - voting to close.

I am not asking anybody to proofread my sentence. My question is "Does a little of a feeling of self-contempt sound idiomatic?".

@Kaguyahime That's exactly what proofreading is. You're not actually asking a question about learning English - you're saying here's my sentence, check if its right or wrong. If we say "no" its not idiomatic, what would you learn? Nothing.

In fact, I've just looked and you've asked TEN questions on this site so far, all "is this idiomatic" or "is this natural" and you've not accepted a single answer that you've been given. The reason people are answering you in comments is because they know they shouldn't be answering an off-topic question and will likely get downvoted for it.

Your logic is completely incomprehensible to me. Simply saying "it is not idiomatic" is definitely a useful answer to me. If you simply said "no", I would realize that I would have to make up a different phrase or search for phrases that native English speakers would use.

@Kaguyahime But you would have learned nothing except that a phrase you wrote is wrong. You wouldn't know why it was wrong. The question and answer would be of no use whatsoever to any future readers of the site because its simply a check on something you wrote. I believe there are other proofreading sites, but this is not one of them.

Considering that this a free site, even a simple answer "no" is a useful answer to this physically handicapped self-learner of English who can not afford to use a paid site. That said, it is true that it is best to use a paid proofreading site.

@Astralbee Your characterisation of the OP is a little harsh and slanted. The OP has posted 88 questions, ten of which —I haven't checked—asking if a phrase is idiomatic. The reason why some questions go unanswered is not for fear of losing a few internet points, it's because the site has lost valuable contributors in the last five or six years . Contributors such as Snailcar/plane, StonyB, Andrew, and J.R. to name but a few.  Fewer answerers, fewer posts, fewer votes etc. It's also rare that any user will post a one-word "yes" or "no" answer, there's normally an accompanying explanation.

@Mari-LouA And out of 88 questions they have accepted answers to 11% of them. You can see from their latest response that their view is "this is a free site" and they have no interest in whether the answers are quality or not. This type of question IS off-topic and should be closed. I had a look on meta to see if 'answers in comments' has ever been addressed and it has - the great J.R. who you namedropped said that comments with answers should be flagged with 'other' and described as such. Do you agree with that?

@Astralbee To me, answers from volunteers are quality answers except in rare cases. Have you not noticed that I upvoted almost all of the answers I received from you? And I did not say I was not interested in whether the answers were quality or not. When I answer a question about Japanese, I try to do my best.

I find the phrase "a little of a feeling of self-contempt" not quite idiomatic but wouldn't truly balk if I encountered it in a story. It is verbose but could be used to suggest, in a story, that the person was searching for the right words.  And while we can "hold someone in contempt", when we say that someone has held a feeling or emotion for a long time, the cliche verb is harbor:

She harbored a bit of self-contempt.
She harbored a great deal of resentment.

See harbor at M-W: "to hold especially persistently in the mind".
“Harbor.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harbor. Accessed 25 Oct. 2024.
